# How should oAuth access tokens from external providers be saved in a Parse user

Tags: oauth, parse-platform

I have an oAuth access token from a third party provider (such as Google/Twitter etc).

I'm using the JavaScript SDK for Parse and need to store/associate these oAuth crendentials to the user they belong to.

I need to:

1. Allow users to have multiple sign-in IDs (some might pick twitter, Google and/or Facebook etc).
2. On top of creating a password for each user.
3. Be able to locate and safely verify the user credentials when presented with the providers user ID and access token.

There doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this on Parse that is secure, since adding a special access token object would be accessible to everyone.  I can't emulate a password using the access token since it's possible it can be modified by the provider.

It's not clear from documentation how Facebook credentials are linked to a Parse user - but I do not the presence of a 'authentication provider' which is being used for this purpose. But using it means hacking on non-public APIs.

**How can Parse be used to store oAuth credentials?**

Comment: I created a tutorial that does just this, using GitHub as an example OAuth provider. https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app It uses 2 new classes, which are secured from public access, and some cloud code to facilitate everything. Also relevant blog posts: http://blog.parse.com/2013/12/03/bring-your-own-login/ http://blog.parse.com/2013/11/04/validating-session-tokens-with-the-rest-api/

Comment: Perfect post - must have missed it. I'm running a Parse app inside a Chrome Package app on iOS/Android so will modify your technique slightly but makes sense. What about Facebooks oAuth? Skip the current ```authData``` attribute on users and use this new method for all login providers? (I tried using 'google' as a provider but get the error ```no supported account linking service found```).

Comment: correct.. if you're doing anything non standard, use this method rather than trying to access the Parse authData/providers model.